# Is there a way to update the "Created By" and "Created" fields on a SharePoint Folder using PNP

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I'm migrating a folder from my local drive to SharePoint Library, and i want to be able to modify the created by fields using powershell. is this possible?

if not is there another alternative in which this can be done?

I am able to do this with add-pnpfile for files but not for folders. something in the nature of

```bsh
$object = @{}
$object.Add("Modified",'1/1/2019')
$object.Add("Editor" ,"jennie.Doe@email.com")
$object.Add("Author" ,"Mac.walkers@email.com")

Add-PnPFile -Path 'C:/users/Newfolder/test.docx' -Folder 'Test/NewFolder' -Values $object
```

where $object is the object holding the properties and values i need to update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample demo:

Key point is getting the folder item and then updating.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteURL -Credentials $PSCredentials

$user=Get-PnPUser | ? Email -eq "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$folderName="NewFolder"
$library=Get-PnPList -Identity MyDoc4
Add-PnPFolder -Name $folderName -Folder $library.RootFolder.Name
$folderURL=[string]::Format("{0}/{1}", $library.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl,$folderName)
$folder=Get-PnPFolder -Url $folderURL
Set-PnPListItem -List "MyDoc4" -Identity $folder.ListItemAllFields -Values @{Editor=""+$user.Id+"";Modified="7/24/2019"}
```

Comment: thank you soo much again, this worked like a charm. i have one more question about Get-PnpUser, does the user need to have access to the SharePoint site for Get-PnPUser to grab his or her details. i noticed that sometimes users i know exist come up as "Null" but when i add the user to the SharePoint site and remove the user i start to get information about the user. So i'm not really sure how get-pnpuser works. Just want to know if it only works for users that have at some point used SharePoint and not people who have an email account but no identity on SharePoint